# kendo ui like datepicker is not working on firefox

Tags: css, angularjs, firefox, kendo-ui

I use Kendo UI with AngularJS. My app is working well in chrome but when I test it in firefox 
the datepicker is not working. I found many post regarding this issue and they said that
the kendo team found the reason of the bug and gave a quick fix:

```
.k-ff { overflow: inherit !important;}
```

They said that you just need to add that class in to your CSS but that didn't work for me.
I just updated my Firefox. My Angular version is v1.2.16 and my Kendo UI version is v2014.2.903.

Comment: Code that you've showed was required in Q1 2014 and it was fixing issue affected with widgets like ditepicker or dropdownlist. When you were trying to open widget's popup it was blinking (open and close instanlty).
What do you mean datpicker not working? Can you show screenshot or fiddle with your issue? Or explain it precisely?

Comment: sorry i don't have enough reputation to post images..
in chrome browser the datepicker displays the date values,callendar button,and time button..

but in firefox only the textbox appears. no datavalue, no calendar button, and no time button

Comment: and i also noticed that when i checked  the dom element of the datepicker is not there.. and few seconds.. the dom element of the 
datepicker suddenly appears.. so i guess the directives for kendo ui datepicker is not working well on firefox?? im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

i found out that the kendo datepicker is working to those who think that the problem is the kendo.. it took a lot of time before i figure out that i was looking for a problem that didn't exist.

on my case.. datepicker is not working because i write the kendo directive inside my custom directive.. the real problem is about my directive and firefox..